# scala: how to return empty object and not None

Tags: scala

```
val customerIdent = custIdentByCustomerId(id).firstOption
customerIdent.getOrElse (None)
```

I do not want to return None, want to return empty customerIdent of type `CustomerIdentification`.

If I do this:

```
customerIdent.getOrElse (None)
```

The compiler says:

```
[error] C:\Code\...\scala\models\Customer.scala:125: type mismatch;
[error] found : None.type [error] required: models.CustomerIdentification 
[error] customer.get.status, customer. get.rec_marketing_messages, customerIdent.getOrElse (None))
```

Please help

Comment: I get this error while compiling: [error] C:\Code\smart-check\common\src\main\scala\models\Customer.scala:125: typ
e mismatch;
[error]  found   : None.type
[error]  required: models.CustomerIdentification
[error]                                           customer.get.status, customer.
get.rec_marketing_messages, customerIdent.getOrElse (None))

Comment: Replace that `None` with what you consider the empty version of whatever class type it is that you desire.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to construct an empty version of CustomerIdentification? Something like:

```
val emptyIdent = CustomerIdentification()
```

Then you could say:

```
val customerIdent = custIdentByCustomerId(id).firstOption
customerIdent.getOrElse(emptyIdent)
```

Comment: I cannot create aan empty object because it requires the parameters: classes...
[error] C:\Code\smart-check\common\src\main\scala\models\Customer.scala:118: not
 enough arguments for method apply: (id: String, customer_id: String, id_type: S
tring, id_number: String, issuer: String, expiration_date: java.sql.Date)models.
CustomerIdentification in object CustomerIdentification.
[error] Unspecified value parameters id, customer_id, id_type, ...
[error]           val emptyIdent = CustomerIdentification()

[error] (common/compile:compile) Compilation failed

Comment: Ah. Well it seems like maybe there isn't such a thing as an "empty" CustomerIdentification. Could your function perhaps have a return type of Option[CustomerIdentification] instead of CustomerIdentifiaction? That way you could return "custIdentByCostmerId(id).firstOption". That sees like the right course to me. If you can find a custId you return Some(custId). If you can't, you return None. Since you can't make an empty CustomerId, you need to use Option[CustomerId]

Comment: I have a a case class with some parameters and this CustomerIdent case class. Something like case class CustomerValue(id: String, first_name: Option[String], customerIdentification: CustomerIdentification). Now the customerIdentification can be non existent in the database, I return CustomerValue and I cannot make the CustomerValue optional as it will be always there. Only the parameter customerIdentification  can be optional which I am trying to set as empty if not found and that's the issue.

Comment: If the customerIdentification can be missing in the database, then maybe  CustomerValue should contain an Option[CustomerIdentification], or you should create a different class that does.

Comment: Let me try that, Thanks